# Activate Desktop PWAs flag in Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to generate an APK file from a progressive web application in Android (device with Android 8.0.0). In order to do that, I have read ([here](https://www.xda-developers.com/progressive-web-apps-chrome-how-to/) for example, but also in other pages), that I have to enable the flag chrome://flags#enable-desktop-pwas. The problem is that flag is unavailable in my android device. It shows the text: Not available on your platform.

I have test that over Chrome, Chrome Dev and Chrome Canary with same result.

Any idea?

Comment: I believe that "app banner" != "app APK". Note that two of the flags in your link do not have Android as a supported OS. And I thought the whole point of a PWA is to skip creating APK in the first place.

Comment: And "desktop" PWAs means non-mobile.